# FFmpeg muxing to avi

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, avi

sI have program, that succefully shows h264 stream using SDL: I'm getting h264 frame, decode it using ffmpeg and draw using SDL.
Also I can write frames to file (using fwrite) and play this file through ffplay.

But I want to mux data to the avi and face some problems in av_write_frame.

Here is my code:

```
...
/*Initializing format context - outFormatContext is the member of my class*/
AVOutputFormat *outFormat;
outFormat = av_guess_format(NULL,"out.avi",NULL);
outFormat->video_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
outFormat->audio_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_NONE;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFormatContext, outFormat, NULL, "out.avi");
AVCodec *outCodec;
AVStream *outStream = add_stream(outFormatContext, &outCodec, outFormatContext->oformat->video_codec);
avcodec_open2(outStream->codec, outCodec, NULL);
av_dump_format(outFormatContext, 0, "out.avi", 1);
if (avio_open(&outFormatContext->pb, "out.avi", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) 
    throw Exception("Couldn't open file");
if (avformat_write_header(outFormatContext, NULL) < 0)
    throw Exception("Couldn't write to file");
 //I don't have exceptions here - so there is 6KB header in out.avi.
 ...

static AVStream *add_stream(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec **codec,
                        enum AVCodecID codec_id)
{
AVCodecContext *c;
AVStream *st;
/* find the encoder */
*codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
if (!(*codec)) 
    throw("Could not find encoder");
st = avformat_new_stream(oc, *codec);
if (!st) 
    throw ("Could not allocate stream");
st->id = oc->nb_streams-1;
c = st->codec;
c->bit_rate = 400000;
/* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
c->width    = 1920;
c->height   = 1080;
c->pix_fmt  = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
c->flags = 0;
c->time_base.num = 1;
c->time_base.den = 25;
c->gop_size      = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
return st;
}
...
/* Part of decoding loop. There is AVPacket packet - h264 packet;
int ret = av_write_frame(outFormatContext, &packet); //it return -22 code - Invadlid argument;
if (avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameDecoded, &packet) < 0) 
    return;
if (frameDecoded)
{
   //SDL stuff
}
```

Also i tried to use avcodec_encode_video2 (encode pFrame back to the H264) next to the SDL stuff but encoding is not working - i've got empty packets :( It is the second problem.

Using av_interleaved_write_frame causes acces violation.

Code of the muxing part i copied from ffmpeg muxing example (https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2muxing_8c-example.html)